# This bit of code is throwing "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I have tried using " if let"

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

    //self.previewImage.image = image
    //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    let pickedImage = self.previewImage.image

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage!)
    let imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: imageData!)!

    PFUser.currentUser()?.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "profileImage")
    PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()

}
```

Comment: where exactly your error happen (which line ) I guess it's in else pickedImage or ImageData , so please tell us what preview Image is and whatiImageData is

Comment: Error is at let imageData..... Compiler is telling me that it is nil.

Comment: What is `self.previewImage.image` and why aren't you using the picked `image` ?

Comment: self.preview.image is @IBOutlet weak var previewImage: UIImageView!

Comment: add an exception breakpoint,and find out line throw the error.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are using the wrong variable. The callback of the image picker gives you the picked image, but you are not using it since the frist two lines are commented.

```
let pickedImage = self.previewImage.image
```

Here you are assigning an UIImageView's image to a new constant called packedImage. If the UIImageView has no default image assigned the `image`property is `nil`.

```
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage!)
```

When you try to access `pickedImage`now, it might be `nil` and result in the error you named.

Perhaps it works this way:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
  if let image = image {
    self.previewImage.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image),
       let imageFile = PFFile(data: imageData),
       let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
         currentUser.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "profileImage")
         currentUser.saveInBackground()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Getting this now. Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'UIImage'

Comment: Great it helped you. If this answer is closing this problem, it would be great if you could mark this as the correct answer. Thank you.